# Combining two string lists

Tags: python, string

Looking to combine two list variables containing string elements.  For example, if I have the below :

```
mystring1 = ['Luke', 'Han']
mystring2 = ['Skywalker', 'Solo']
```

I am looking to combine them to be :

```
mystring3 = ['LukeSkywalker', 'HanSolo']
```

I am sure I am missing something simple.  Any guidance would be great!

Comment: Use a for loop. Have you tried....it is not difficult

Comment: mystring3[0] = mystring1 [0]+mystring2 [0] take this hint

Comment: consider accepting an answer. Doesn't necessarily have to be my answer, but the one you found most useful.

Answer (score 9):

Simply `map` the two lists to `str.__add__`:

```
list(map(str.__add__, mystring1, mystring2))
```

This outputs:

```
['LukeSkywalker', 'HanSolo']
```

As a side note, if you want to combine more than two lists of strings at a time, you can do:

```
mystring1 = ['Luke', 'Han']
mystring2 = ['Skywalker', 'Solo']
mystring3 = ['Hero', 'Sidekick']
from functools import partial, reduce
print(list(reduce(partial(map, str.__add__), (mystring1, mystring2, mystring3))))
```

This outputs:

```
['LukeSkywalkerHero', 'HanSoloSidekick']
```

Comment: Great I never knew `map` took multiple iterables. You could remove the need for using the dunder method if you used [`operator.add`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#operator.add)

Comment: thank you!!!  this is great.

Comment: @JDV_ny Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you think it is correct?

Answer (score 5):

The following should work:

```
>>> mystring1 = ['Luke', 'Han']
>>> mystring2 = ['Skywalker', 'Solo']
>>> list(map(''.join, zip(mystring1, mystring2)))
['LukeSkywalker', 'HanSolo']
>>>
```

Comment: `list(map(''.join, zip(mystring1, mystring2)))`.  No need to map `str` over anything.

Comment: @BradSolomon removed the outer `list()` also coz `zip()` returns list itself

Comment: In Python 2, yes.  In Python 3, you need `list()`.

Comment: ok. Added then.

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip) and then concatenate the strings.

This obviously only works if there are exactly two strings you wish to join. If there were more, then use `str.join` like some of the other answers suggest. With 2 strings however the concat method is more readable.

```
>>> mystring1 = ['Luke', 'Han']
>>> mystring2 = ['Skywalker', 'Solo']
>>> 
>>> [s1 + s2 for s1, s2 in zip(mystring1, mystring2)]
['LukeSkywalker', 'HanSolo']
```

`zip` simply takes one element from each of the iterables passed to it, on each iteration and returns a tuple of those elements. The intermediate result of the `zip` operation looks like

```
[('Luke', 'Skywalker'), ('Han', 'Solo')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1], zip(mystring1, mystring2))
```

Zipping the two produces an iterable (or list, if you're in Python 2) of 2-tuples. Then `map` over the iterable (resp. list) to convert to the result you want.

Comment: You can also do `map(lambda x, y: x + y, mystring1, mystring2)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
mystring1 = ['Luke', 'Han']
mystring2 = ['Skywalker', 'Solo']
df=pd.DataFrame([mystring1,mystring2]).T
df.columns=list('01')
print((df['0']+df['1']).tolist())
```

Output:

```
['LukeSkywalker', 'HanSolo']
```